# Android SDK tools not generating adbkey.pub

Tags: ubuntu, android, sdk, adb

When connecting my phone (galaxy S8 with lightRom v14) to pc (ubuntu 18.10) it asks me to allow file access (mtp i guess) but doesn't ask for adb permission (no dialog). When inspecting `.android` on my pc i found out that adbkey was here but adbkey.pub was missing. Tried deleting adbkey and running `adb kill-server && adb start-server`, changing folder permissions, uninstalling whole android studio and removing sdk, even running adb with sudo privileges, but without any luck, adbkey is the only file created. Also tried removing all android keys from system using `Passwords and Keys` utility, removing and changing password to login keystore, but without any effect.
`adbkey.pub` file is required if i want to manually allow adb access to this phone (by moving it into /data/misc/adb/adb_keys on the phone) but since it's missing i cannot do anything.

Comment: Enable USB debugging option from Developer options in Settings.

Comment: Tried that several times, even turned off and on developer settings tab. Revoke USB permission is missing in android 9.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by installing `adb` from Ubuntu repo, now adbkey.pub gets generated and everything works like a charm.